# font family css uses incorrect font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am working on a large website that I am converting from static to responsive design. I've run into a strange issue where my font family CSS no longer works. I am using a custom font we purchased (HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma). Below is my CSS:

```
.secondLevel ul a{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma";
}
```

When I view the inspector I can see the font-family is recognized, and is being used. However, the font does not display with the correct family (see screenshot). Does anybody know what the issue could be? I have tried swapping the font family for another HelveticaNeue (HelveticaNeueW01-85Heav), and that works perfectly fine. It's only when I use the 55Roma that caused an issue.

Screenshot:
[image: incorrect font fmaily]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are properly defining your font family with `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma";
    src: url("path/to/HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma.woff");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @taxicala! I'm giving this a try right now.

Comment: So I have found the other font (85 Heavy) declared with font-face, and I am missing the declaration for the particular one that is incorrect. However, this is the same code that is being used in a previous version of the site, and the 55 Roma font works fine using the same browser. Should I need to include the font-face for 55 Roma in addition to the 85 Heavy? If so, I'm confused as to why it worked before.

Comment: Probably yes as they are different fonts.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to work through this.. I will come back and mark the answer as correct if this works for me. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem! glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you are including all of the various forms of the font as well, .woff, ttf, eot, etc etc.

Different browsers support different formats.